# Dynamically insert more UITextFields

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

I have a requirement as described in the attached screen shot. When blue add button is clicked, one more `UItextfield` have to be inserted between last text field and textview and Blue add button will have to appear beside that dynamically inserted new uitextfield. Could any one suggest how to achieve this. I have placed all the fields in `UIScrollview`.

[image]

Scroll view is not enabled:

[image]

Comment: have you tried anythink for it???

Comment: Check my answer it w'll run sucessully as per your screen shot..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do as :

In .h I have an outlet called `previousTextField` which is hooked to the first one. As name suggests it will store the latest added textField.

Find running [project here](http://www.keepandshare.com/doc/6029739/dynamicallyadduitextfield-34k?da=y).

```
-(IBAction)addTextField:(id)sender{
    float x=previousTextField.frame.origin.x;
    float y=previousTextField.frame.origin.y+50;//get y from previous textField and add 10 or so in it.
    float w=previousTextField.frame.size.width;
    float h=previousTextField.frame.size.height;
    CGRect frame=CGRectMake(x,y,w,h);
    UITextField *textField=[[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    textField.placeholder = @"Enter User Name or Email";


    textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    textField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
    textField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
    textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
    textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;


    [self.view addSubview:textField];
    previousTextField=textField;
}
```

<strike>*Just an idea/algorithm how to go with, not compiler checked*</strike>

I missed on thing, changing the location of <kbd>+</kbd> button. I think you can do it :)

**EDIT: add following in above method**

```
//move addbutton which is an outlet to the button
CGRect frameButton=CGRectMake(addButton.frame.origin.x, addButton.frame.origin.y+50, addButton.frame.size.width, addButton.frame.size.height);
[addButton removeFromSuperview];
[addButton setFrame:frameButton];
[self.view addSubview:addButton];
```

Comment: I am getting following error...Use of undeclared identifier NSFrame. do I have to import any package or where is NSFrame declared

Comment: Sorry it should be NSMakeRect, I simply typed here without checking :p

Comment: I am unable to view the added textfield. could you please have a look

Comment: @iHungry, thank you for the nice answer. My req is little different..button also should move along with newly created uitextfiled. But, I am able to get it..Thank you very much.

Comment: @RamuPasupuleti: Thanking to iHungry :D. giving credits to him in place of me  rofl.

Comment: As i mentioned button should move, that not a big deal, that is why I commented that you can do it.

Comment: So here you go with your exact requirement

Comment: @Anoop Vaidya, I have one more question..Why my scroll view not enabled. I am attaching the screen shot in updated question. Please have a look

Answer (score 0):

On add button add a textfeild in subview and give the textfeild a unique tag so it will help you to differentiate between all textfeilds. For setting frame take the reference of your last textfeild frame and accordingly set the y coordinate.

```
UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:yourFrame];
textField.delegate = self;
textField.tag=yourtag;
[scrollview addSubview:textField];
[textField release];//if arc is disable
```

Answer (score 0):

First get the frame of the UItextField. Now increase yPos of the previous textFeild and at UITetField new position. And to re arrange UITextField which are below that textField just increase yPos of each TextField.

Answer (score 0):

see output of my code..
[image]

You can use following code...i have done it & it is running as per your screen shot..
in your .h file just declare this variable

```
      int newY,newY1;
      UIButton *btn;
```

then your .m file in viewDidLoad method add following code

```
   UITextField *txt=[[UITextField alloc]init];
   txt.frame=CGRectMake(50,30,140,30);
   txt.placeholder = @"Enter User Name or Email";
   txt.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;

   [self.view addSubview:txt];
   newY=txt.frame.origin.y;
   btn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeContactAdd];
   btn.frame=CGRectMake(250,30, 30, 30);
   [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(addtxtField) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
   [self.view addSubview:btn];
```

& then create one addtxtField method..see below

```
 -(void)addtxtField
{
newY=newY+50;

UITextField *nwtxt=[[UITextField alloc]init];
nwtxt.frame=CGRectMake(50,newY,140,30);
nwtxt.placeholder = @"Enter User Name or Email";
nwtxt.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
[self.view addSubview:nwtxt];

btn.frame=CGRectMake(250,newY, 30, 30);
[self.view addSubview:btn];
```

}

it is 100% running as per your requiement...

Answer (score 0):

[image: Output]

Try this ::

In .h file

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scr;
@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *txt;
@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextView *txtVw;
@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *btn;

-(IBAction)click:(id)sender;
```

In .m file

```
int cnt;

float x = 0.0, y = 0.0, w = 0.0, h = 0.0;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    scr.delegate = self;
    scr.contentSize = CGSizeMake(0, 400);

    cnt = 0;
}

-(IBAction)click:(id)sender
{
    if (cnt == 0) {
       x=txt.frame.origin.x;
       y=txt.frame.origin.y + 50;//get y from previous textField and add 10 or so in it.
       w=txt.frame.size.width;
       h=txt.frame.size.height;
    }
    else
    {
       y+=50;
    }

    UITextField *textField=[[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, w, h)];
    textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    textField.placeholder = @"Enter User Name or Email";

    [scr addSubview:textField];

    [btn setFrame:CGRectMake(248, y, 30, 30)];

    float y1 = y + 100;
    [txtVw setFrame:CGRectMake(orign_x, y1, origin_w, origin_h)];

    cnt++;
}
```

Hope, it'll definately help you.

Thanks.

Comment: Then set contensize of scrollview accrording to text fields.

Comment: along with the new textfield, we have to create new button. When user clicks on new button, another textfield should appear

Comment: @RamuPasupuleti: accroding to your screen, button is moving. My code is working in that manner. or you can add new button dynmically. But I think, that's not your need.