# How to move button action ios

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios5, uibutton

i want to change positon of button when it is pressed, it should move below again and agin when keep pressing , please tell me what should i do?

```
textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(76, ([txtFieldArray count] * 30), 191, 25)];
[textField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleLine];
textField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:20];
textField.placeholder = @"Enter text";
textField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
textField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
textField.delegate = self;
[myScrollview addSubview:textField];
[txtFieldArray addObject:textField];

CGRect frame = bottomView.frame;
frame.origin.y += textField.frame.size.height + 5;

bottomView.frame = frame;
textField.hidden = NO;
```

Comment: what is wrong with this code?

Comment: below this code i want to add button , when textfield is added button also change position

Comment: can u tell me programatically how to change position of button?

Comment: yes,like you changerd textfield, you can change the position of button, by changing its frame

Comment: i did this but it didn t change poition , can you explain your ans?

Comment: what is bottomView in your code?

Comment: it is another view in a scroll view, botom view geos down when textfield is added

Comment: @QualityCoder: please check my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15539690/dynamically-insert-more-uitextfields/15539758#15539758)

Answer (score 0):

After creating UIButton and setting it's frame like UITextField, you should use button's `setFrame:` method to change the position of it.

If you like to change the position with pressing button, first create a `-(IBAction *)buttonPressed:(id)sender` method and set button's new position in it. Then add the `[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]` method after where you create the button.

Comment: In the buttonPressed method use [((UIButton *)sender) setFrame:newFrame] method

Comment: When you set new frame, the button's position change to new frame. What else you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

Give the frame of the button in you described snippet only.

For ex,

```
<button_object>.frame =
CGRectMake(textField.frame.origin.x,textField.frame.origin.y +
x,textField.size.width,textField.size.height);


Where X = the difference upto which you want to add the button after
textfield. For ex, 44 or 50 or so on..
```

Enjoy Programming!

Answer (score 0):

you can assign an tag to the button as

```
UIButton *btn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[btn setTag:100];
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(moveButtonDown) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

and whenever the button is clicked the frame for the button can be changed by getting a reference of the button.In the code below i have moved down the button by 20 pixels. You can change this value to what ever you want .

```
 -(void)moveButtonDown
{
    UIButton *btn=(UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:100];
    float y=btn.frame.origin.y;
    y+=20;
    [btn setFrame:CGRectMake(btn.frame.origin.x, y, btn.frame.size.width, btn.frame.size.height)];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify your code by:

```
CGRect frame = bottomView.frame;
frame.origin.y += (tField.frame.origin.y+textField.frame.size.height + 5);

bottomView.frame = frame;
textField.hidden = NO;
```