# How to create automatically labels by a button?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I have a button,a textfield and some labels.I want create labels by a button display with **scroll**

Textfield is Number repeat or copy of labels.User when enter 5 to textfield labels will like ;

LabelA    LabelB      LabelC  (Original labels)

LabelA2   LabelB2     LabelC2

LabelA3   LabelB3     LabelC3

LabelA4   LabelB4     LabelC4

LabelA5   LabelB5     LabelC5

Comment: for loops and UILabels and correct frames combined with UIScrollview should do this feature for you. But you have to make an attempt first.

Comment: [Check here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15539690/dynamically-insert-more-uitextfields/15539758#15539758), you can modify it by calling the action of `add` with labels instead of textfields

Answer (score 2):

On button action

- get the numberOfRows from textfield as `[textField.text intValue]`
- Then in a loop Create label programatically setting frame properly

Something like this

For giving you an idea ,not the real working code,this is for snigle column Do for 3 labels added programatically with suitable frame

```
 for (int i=0; i<[textField.text intValue]; i++)
    {
        UILabel *label= [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(X, Y, Width, height)];
        [self.view addSubview:label];
    }
```