# Adding textfield dynamically to table view cell and scroll it horizontally

Tags: ios, uitableview, dynamic, uiscrollview

I have created an table view shown in landscape orientation.

I want to add multiple text fields dynamically to table cell and also want to get data can any one suggest me. How can I scroll it horizontally in iOS?

Answer (score 0):

```
   UITextField *mytextField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, 10, 185, 30)];
        mytextField.clearsOnBeginEditing = NO;
        mytextField.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
        mytextField.delegate = self;  
        [yourCell.contentView addSubview: mytextField];
```

or

try like this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }

       if (indexPath.row == 0){
     21)];
    self.mytextField1 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120, 13, 375, 30)];
    self.mytextField1.placeholder = @"mytextField1";
    self.mytextField1.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    [self.mytextField1 setClearButtonMode:UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing];

    [cell addSubview:self.mytextField1];
}

if (indexPath.row == 1){
    self.mytextField2 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120, 13, 375, 30)];
    self.mytextField2.placeholder = @"mytextField2";
    self.mytextField2.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    [self.mytextField2 setClearButtonMode:UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing];

    [cell addSubview:self.mytextField2];
}

if (indexPath.row == 2){
    // add here 
}

if (indexPath.row == 3){

}

self.mytextField1.delegate = self;
self.mytextField2.delegate = self;
// and other also here


cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

        return cell;
    }
```

Comment: i want to add all text fields on same cell not on different cells and then scroll it horizontally. and if i get to input for 20-25 text fields then how can i generate it dynamically.

Comment: why you want to add in same cell ?

Comment: its my project requirement add those text field get input and shown in landscape orientation.and add run time new row to the table view

Comment: or use UIScrollview and a custom UIview in top of add UITextfield and add how manny you want to add text filed by runtime .

Comment: for (int i = indexPath.row ; i < 15; i++) { UITextField *valueTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8 + 102 * i , 10,94,21)]; 
 valueTextField.tag = i + 1;  valueTextField.borderStyle = TextBorderStyleRoundedRect; [valueTextField setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDefault]; [valueTextField setEnablesReturnKeyAutomatically:YES]; [valueTextField setDelegate:self]; valueTextField.placeholder=@"P_!_Add";
 valueTextField.backgroundColor=[UIColor grayColor];             [cell.contentView addSubview:valueTextField]; }

Comment: i did this to add text fields but their position is not same for every reuse cell .

Comment: check this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15539690/dynamically-insert-more-uitextfields

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding textField directly into tableCell you can first add a scroll view on tableCell than add multiple textField on this scroll view. Set the content size accordingly of scroll view, so that it will scroll easily to the end.